# npm registry local clone to reduce duplication of packages

Tags: node.js, npm, local

I was just wondering if there exists a way such that instead of downloading the fresh npm package(s) for each new node js project, we can download regularly used packages and dev-dependencies on local machine with various versions and then utilise in node js project. In short, I would like to download npm packages for once from npm registry and save locally under file system and for any new project which requires one or more of these packages, I can refer the localfile system path and no need to download fresh package from npm registry. Main objective is to keep redundency at lowest level as possible.Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure npm to use a proxy server.

```
# For HTTP
npm config set proxy http://your-proxy-server:8080

# For HTTPS
npm config set https-proxy https://your-proxy-server:8443
```

You can use nginx, varnish or squid as a reverse proxy cache. That would store a copy of the downloaded files and you can configure how exactly that is done and for how long. Note that npm itself also caches files.

Comment: Where will this store the NPM packages as a cache? Will this allow me to use few version of the same npm package on multiple projects ?

Comment: What this does is give you a cached copy each time you attempt to download an already downloaded file. The reverse proxy cache would store the files on disk.

Comment: Will this accomodate multiple versions of the same NPM package or will server the cached one only ? If I have specified newer version in package.json and if I run "npm install", what will this do ?

Comment: This is just an HTTP cache, it doesn't know anything about npm. Each npm package has a unique URL, each version will be cached independently. If you request a file that is not cached, it will download it. If you request a file that is cached, it will give you the cached copy rather than download it.

Comment: Ok great ! So I can use the .npmrc to lock the version of npm package and still use old/cached packages along with ask for new version of the package to be downloaded as specified in pacjage.json file... correct ?

Comment: Again: this is just an HTTP cache, it doesn't know anything about npm whatsoever. This just affects npm's HTTP client so downloaded files are cached. Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting solution is: http://www.verdaccio.org/

It does what you need with little configuration. It is well documented and maintained.

I installed it in a small machine within our company's internal network and all my team added it as the npm registry.